# Move an uploaded file in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to move uploaded images from a temporary location.

The path of an uploaded temp image is as follows:

> /storage/tmp/posts/14916460012147460153.jpg

To move the image i am using Storage::move() facade.

```
  $__fn = basename( $tmpImage );
  Storage::move( 
    storage_path( 'app' ) . '/public/tmp/posts/' . $__fn,
    storage_path( 'app' ) . '/public/images/'.Auth::id().'/posts/' . $__fn
  );
```

But it throws an error:

> FileNotFoundException in Filesystem.php line 385:
>
> File not found at path: 
>   D:\Projects\expo\storage\app/public/tmp/posts/14916460012147460153.jpg

Though the file exists and can be found via browser at localhost:8000/storage/tmp/posts/14916460012147460153.jpg

I read the doc of laravel [filesystem](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#storing-files), but cant understand what is missing here.

Comment: Make sure that this file exists `D:\Projects\expo\storage\app/public/tmp/posts/14916460012147460153.jpg`!!!

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH Yes the file exists and can be found via browser at http://localhost:8000/storage/tmp/posts/14916460012147460153.jpg

Comment: Please try `Storage::disk('public')->move('tmp/posts/' . $__fn', 'images/'.Auth::id().'/posts/' . $__fn);`

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH Thanks a ton. Please post your comment as answer so i can accept it :)

Comment: You are welcome ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use the disk instance instead of the `Storage` facade and absolute paths:

```
Storage::disk('public')->move(
    'tmp/posts/' . $__fn, 
    'images/'. Auth::id() . '/posts/' . $__fn);
```